# CMAKE linker does not find library; but library is found with find_library

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, catkin

I have a catkin library under the Name mylib which I build with `catkin build`
Furthermore, I have a node in which uses functions from this library. I enabled this link as I usually do in the CMakeLists.txt of the node:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  mylib
)

add_executable(exec
  src/main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(exec
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

However it did not succeed this time. Linker error
I then added:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  mylib
)
find_library( MYLIB NAMES
    mylib
)
message(${MYLIB})

add_executable(exec
  src/main.cpp
)

add_dependencies(exec ${MYLIB})

target_link_libraries(exec
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${MYLIB}
)
```

The thing is the message() statement prints the correct path of the library, where i can also find it in the explorer.
However I get the warning:

```
(add_dependencies):   Policy CMP0046 is not set: Error on non-existent dependency in   add_dependencies.
```

Which refers to the exact same path for the library and says it is not existent.

The linker error is

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib
```

Remark: I could solve the error by adding the path to the library manually

```
link_directories($ENV{HOME}/test/devel/lib)
```

I do not understand why the library is found first, but cannot be linked as its package name. But it works by providing the full path.
I appreciate any insight!

Comment: In any case, remove `add_dependencies` call: This function adjusts dependencies between **targets**, but path to the library is not a *target*.

Answer (score 1):

The library is not in your linker path. E.g. your linker looks in `/link` and you have a lib in `/home`. You know where to look and can see it in your file browser but the linker won't find it because it only looks in '/link'.

'find_package' looks for the package and sets some variables but it doesn't change the linker path.

You have to set the linker path by yourself. In most cases `find_package` sets a variable containing the linker path.

`find_package` provides some functions like `catkin_package()`. These functions set your build environment.

> catkin_package() is a catkin-provided CMake macro. This is required to specify catkin-specific information to the build system which in turn is used to generate pkg-config and CMake files.
>
> This function must be called before declaring any targets with add_library() or add_executable().